# Increase height and width of a boottrap 4 card when collapsed?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

**Scenario :**

- I have the following section which contain a card , 
  **when I click the card exapnds and shows the info (card-block) at the same time**

**Todo :**

- I want the width and height to increase,

  Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/5bwryt1g/3/

  **NOTE:** it may not work in jsfidle but in my locahost works

**HTML :**

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#test-block" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="test-block">
            card header
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="test-block" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-block">
            card block
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current Scenario :**

- Right now t just expand and shows data but am not  able to make the width and height increase.

What do I need to do get what I want?

Comment: did you mean height and width of `test-block` div ?

Comment: Height and min of  a card

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Jquery.js` order Above `bootstrap.js`

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="test-block" class="collapse">
        <div class="card-body">
            card block
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5bwryt1g/8/

Comment: Hii, Thanks for that , but how can I increase the height and min of card when expanded?

Comment: if I want the whole card to change the size of width and height not only the body?

Comment: Thanks tadhani for your help, if you dont mind I mean when clicked the whole card changes its size width or height here is the image of what I want https://ibb.co/jc1PvU, check the first card when clicked it exapand and the height of card is changed , how can I do that using jquery?